# Inputlistener doesn't handle input on actor

Tags: java, android, libgdx, scene

I put the following Table button in my MenuScreen.java file to make a "start game" button:

```
// register the button "start game"
        TextButton startGameButton = new TextButton( "Start game", getSkin() );
        startGameButton.setTouchable(Touchable.enabled);
        startGameButton.addListener( new InputListener() {

            public boolean touchDown (InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
                System.out.println("down");
                Gdx.app.log( HowDrunkAreYou.LOG, "touch d" );
                return true;
        }

            public void touchUp(
                InputEvent event,
                float x,
                float y,
                int pointer,
                int button )
            {
                Gdx.app.log( HowDrunkAreYou.LOG, "touch d" );
                super.touchUp( event, x, y, pointer, button );
                game.getSoundManager().play( HowDrunkAreYouSound.CLICK );
                //game.setScreen( new StartGameScreen( game ) );
            }
        } );
        table.add( startGameButton ).size( 300, 60 ).uniform().spaceBottom( 10 );
```

For some reason the input handler never fires, java debugger never enters the method. What am I missing? I have tested it on desktop and android, same result.

Neither logcat or console gives me any information about what may be the error.

Thank you!

Comment: r u using stage?? is yes then are u putting Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage) in your code???

Comment: I don't think so. I'm actually pretty new to this. What's exactely stage and where should it be? I'm not using gdx.input.setinputprocessor.

Comment: this link will help you. http://steigert.blogspot.in/2012/03/4-libgdx-tutorial-tablelayout.html    Right now all i can tell you is that you need to make a stage, add table to it , and pass stage to setinputprocessor() . for more detail refer this link and you will learn more about stage and using tables

Comment: Thanks, I read the tutorial, now I solved it. I had to put a setInputProcessor command in my abstractscreen file. Submit as an answer please, so I can accept. Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage) in your code. this link will help you. [steigert blogspot](http://steigert.blogspot.in/2012/03/4-libgdx-tutorial-tablelayout.html)

Right now all i can tell you is that you need to make a stage, add table to it , and pass stage to setinputprocessor() . for more detail refer this link and you will learn more about stage and using tables